# sentence meaning, who performs the action

Tags: meaning

> He threatens the kid to finish the work.

Who is performing the action "finish the work",

He or the kid.

Comment: Sorry but the sentence is not correct English. Please can you tell us its source? Did you invent it yourself or did you read it somewhere?

Comment: “Pressured” might be the intended word here; “threatened” doesn’t work, as @BillJ explains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *He threatens the kid* [*to finish the work.*]

This sentence is ungrammatical because the catenative verb "threaten" can't take an infinitival clause as complement when there is an intervening noun phrase (here, "the kid") between the two verbs.

"Threaten" can occur freely, though, with *to*-infinitival complements in simple catenative constructions, i.e. the kind without an intervening noun phrase:

*He threatened* [*to leave*].

*She threatened* [*to tell her father*].

Comment: If his work is “threatening the kid” this sentence might be grammatical... probably not the intended meaning, though.